# Подключение к существующему vpn через adb

Tags: android, linux, adb

На смартфоне настроено VPN-соединение (l2tp).
Подключение выполняю вручную через Settings > VPN.
Хочется вручную через скрипт (adb) производить подключение/отключение VPN.